# LDAP authentication with PHP application on samba system

Tags: php, authentication, ldap, samba

I set OpenLDAP on a samba system. In ldap, there is users in different cn and ou. I have an application in PHP which authenticate users from AD. I got connection ldap with my application. But not bind user with an application during authentication. I want to know that how to authenticate users from php application to AD which is on samba machine. Here is core code.

```
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("test.com") or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn,'admin','admin12345');
var_dump($ldapbind);
exit;
```

I got bool(false) for ldap bind.

I got an error : **ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Strong(er) authentication required**

Comment: I got authentication using AD which is not on samba system and I done that. But I can't authenticate users with AD which is on samba system.

Comment: Pleas show us the code you're having issues with. It's hard for us to pin point the problem if we don't know what your code looks like.

Comment: code added. Please check it.